# Finding the largest rectangular shaped contour

Tags: opencv, image-processing, python-3.7

Localizing the number plate.

I'm working on number plate recognition project. While localizing the plate I'm taking all the rectangle shaped contours first then selecting the largest contour from them.

```py
for img in images:
    gray_image_array = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  #convert to grayscale
    resized = imutils.resize(gray_image_array, width=300)
    ratio = gray_image_array.shape[0] / float(resized.shape[0])
    #gray_image_mf = median_filter(gray_image_array, 1) #applying unsharp mask filter
    ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(gray_image_array,150,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY) #thresholding
    thresh1 = cv2.bitwise_not(thresh1)

    #......applying canny edge detection....

    v = np.median(thresh1)
    sigma=0.33
    lower = int(max(0, (1.0 - sigma) * v))
    upper = int(min(255, (1.0 + sigma) * v))
    edges = cv2.Canny(thresh1,100,200)

    #...canny ends......

    #.......applying dilation.....

    kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
    dilation = cv2.dilate(edges,kernel,iterations = 2)
    closing = cv2.morphologyEx(dilation, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

    #.........dilation ends.......

    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closing.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    #im = cv2.drawContours(closing,contours,-1,(255,0,0),5)
    h,w,_ = img.shape
    mask = np.zeros((h+2,w+2), np.uint8)
    for c in contours:
            poly = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02*cv2.arcLength(c,True),True)
            if len(poly) == 4:
              # if the contour has 4 vertices then floodfill that contour with black color
                co = max(c, key = cv2.contourArea)
                cnt = np.vstack(co).squeeze()
                ret,closing,mask,_ = cv2.floodFill(closing, mask, tuple(cnt[0]), 0)

    plt.imshow(closing,cmap="gray")
    plt.show()
```

Getting the error

```
<ipython-input-17-4161649b8e06> in <module>
       co = max(c, key = cv2.contourArea)
       cnt = np.vstack(co).squeeze()
 --->  ret,closing,mask,_ = cv2.floodFill(closing, mask, tuple(cnt[0]), 0)

       plt.imshow(closing,cmap="gray")
```

[one of my image is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQvM4.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (good) questions around here. Please provide a [mre], i.e. code (and maybe data, images, if necessary/important), that can be copy-pasted and run as is. By now, the given code and error message are incomplete, e.g. please provide the full error traceback.

Comment: Should I provide my entire code and my expected result??

Comment: 1) Provide the WHOLE error traceback. Which line is actually affected? 2) Provide ONLY the NECESSARY code to fully reproduce the given error. `findContours` gets some `closing` variable, which is out of the scope of the presented code. 3) Provide the image, if necessary to reproduce the error. Does the error always occur or just for certain images?

Comment: 1) I have edited my post and also gave the full error traceback. I have taken the full image folder as input which includes number plate images.The error occurs for all images.2) closing is the output of the closing morphological operation. 3) I have also provided one of my image

Comment: In the affected line, changing `tuple(cnt[0])` to just `cnt` works for me. At least, the code runs; I can't comment on if the result is correct or not.